# Mirror any Android app that is in background or when the device is on sleep

Tags: android, mirroring

Let me first explain my requirement.

**Basic requirement**
We have an Android device (Say sender device) and a bunch of apps that are installed on it. On the sender device we are using app1. We need to display the same app on another Android device (Say receiver device) and use it from there. Here are the limitations.

1. We can install only one app on the receiver device. All the apps that we want to use on receiver device cannot be installed on it. We will be installing a sender app on the sender device and a receiver app on receiver device.
2. We cannot do code changes on any app that we want to display on the receiver device. We should be able to display and use a generic app.
3. We must display and use app1 from the receiver device when the sender device is in sleep mode.
4. We must display and use app1 from receiver device when app1 is in the background in sender (What we have on the foreground of sender is another app).

**Current solution**
We are using Screen Mirroring. No difference from any screen mirroring app that is used in Android ecosystem. So, when app1 is on the foreground and sender is not on sleep we are good. The issue we have is we cannot do the mirroring while the sender device is on sleep and app1 is on the background in sender device.

**Questions**
Here are the questions.

1. Is it possible to achieve this when the sender is in sleep mode? If yes what is the methodology?
2. Is it possible to achieve this when app1 is in the background? If yes what is the methodology?
3. Are there any other alternatives to the current method Screen Mirroring?

Comment: "Is it possible to achieve this when the sender is in sleep mode?" -- at best, this will be up to the developers of the apps and the firmware running on the sender device. At worst, the answer is no. "Is it possible to achieve this when app1 is in the background?" -- no. "Are there any other alternatives to the current method Screen Mirroring?" -- find and use a compatible touchscreen monitor instead of a second device, and keep the first device constantly powered on.